# Separatibility of wave-function in Schrodinger equation describing motion of particle in spherical shell

Tags: schroedinger-equation, mathematics, differential-equations, quantum-chemistry

**Question.**
Why wave-function describing rotation of particle around spherical surface is separable?
Why solution obtained assuming function is separable is general solution?
I am interested in proof of that (see P.S.).

**Explanation of the question.** For thous who are not familiar with the topic.
I don't need the solution of this equation, It can be found in 301 page of Atkins textbook of physical chemistry, 8th edition. The solutions are known as spherical harmonics.

Here is this wave-function.
$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \psi(x,y,z)=E \psi(x,y,z)$$
It can be expressed like this in spherical polar coordinates, assuming that radius is constant.
$$\Lambda^2\psi(\theta,\phi)=\epsilon \psi(\theta,\phi)$$,
where $\Lambda^2$ is the Legendrian:
$$
\Lambda^2 = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$
and $\epsilon=\frac{2IE}{\hbar^2}$.
And I need to prove that for any wave-function staisfying the diffferential equation there are $\Theta(\theta)$ and $\Phi(\phi)$ $\forall \theta \forall \phi[\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)]$.
That is:
$$\forall \psi [\forall \theta \forall \phi \Lambda^2\psi(\theta,\phi)=\epsilon \psi(\theta,\phi) \implies 
\exists \Theta \exists \Phi \forall \theta \forall \phi[\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)]] $$

**Relevance.**
Wave-function describing rotation of particle in spherical shell is used to construct wave-function that describes electron motion in hydrogen atom. Similar arguments are popular in textbooks about quantum chemistry. In several similar cases it is assumed that these wave-function are separable.

**My attempt.**
I have tried to find the solution for several days with no success. For some people this might seem like homework-like (too simple to answer) question. In these case please suggest few classical comprehensible for chemist textbooks where this question is discussed.

**My research.**
In the Atkins textbook of Physical chemistry is 8th edition is justification of wave-function separability. There are several other similar examples.
Author stares that separability can be inferred by plugging in differential equation and seeing that it is possible to obtain two single variable differential equations. I am guessing that author see that it should be self-evident that wave-function is separable. So I hove answer should be simple.

**P.S.**
*About self-evidence.* I am a chemist. Mathematicians and physicians often find some things that other people don't understand as self-evident. They are self evident for them probably because they work with them frequently. This why proofs are needed.

*What proofs are.* So I need list of statements that starts from things I believe (axioms, assumptions or well-known theorems) and than by known inference rules conclusion is derived. Each step must be executed formally. It is good if proof comes from book or publication.
I would like to have proof in predicate logic.
I am not interested in the algorithm that is used to solve this kind of problems on the exam. I want to know why it works. At least this algorithm should have a name (e.g. Theorem lalala). Or this algorithm may be composed of several theorems.

**About the answer I have accepted.**
It looked like something I wanted, but it is a sketch of proof. It would be good to have more details. As I have asked I would like to have proof written in predicate logic.

Comment: Do you mean that the particle is moving **on** a spherical surface?

Comment: Yes. In the textbook this topic is named as "Rotation in three dimensions: the particle on a sphere".

Comment: Can you add to your question the differential equation for which this is the solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm with doublefelix on that.

Comment: The TISE for an electron in spherical coordinates is always separable  but that doesn't necessarily yield a solution though...

Comment: The SE for an electron moving on a sphere is in $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Comment: I corrected that. Thank You.

Comment: Does the spherical shell have some sirt of thickness??

Comment: No. Radius is constant. This problem is described in Atkins Physical Chemistry textbook, 8th edition, 301 page. This book is in google search.

Comment: In my question I mentioned motion of electron around hydrogen nucleus, in that case there is thickness. Solution of problem about motion of particle on spherical shell is used to obtain solution for the hydrogen atom problem.

Comment: "Update...  I am primarily interested in verifying method by which separability of function is obtained" It's an ansatz. It's obtained by making a guess. You check that the guess works and that it the only justification you need.

Comment: I think it is was perfectly clear what I was asking for. Nontheless I made it more clead. When I was it asking I made my point clear by paraphrasing what I want several time and by explaining in detail what I am interested in. I think that the question was a bit long because of this. I am asking only what is in question section. Other sections are ment for clearifying my question. Please reopen my question.

Comment: Yes. But how do I know that obtained solution for separable function is true in general. Suppose that both separable and inseparable functiions satisfy the differential equation. How do I know that inseparable functions doesn't satisfy the differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the angular momentum operator $L_z={\hbar \over i}(x{\partial \over \partial y}-y{\partial \over \partial x})=-i\hbar{\partial \over \partial \phi}$. Show that $[L_z,H]=0$ where $H=\Lambda^2$ is the Hamiltonian. Since they commute, the eigenfunctions of $L_z$ make the eigenfunctions of $H$, and since $L_z$ only depends on the variable $\phi$, the solutions of $H$ must be separable.

Comment: This answer looks like something I was looking for. Could you explain it in a little more detail. I hope this argument is well-known and is in some classical textbook about this topic, preferably that chemist can comprehend.

Comment: The answer of hft just listed the complete form of $\Lambda^2$, and you can plug it in $[L_z,\Lambda^2]$ and the result is easy to see (a more rigorous way to show $[L_z,\Lambda^2]=0$ is to calculate $[L_z,\Lambda^2]\psi(\theta,\phi)=0$ for any wavefunction $\psi(\theta,\phi)$). The thought of commutation between Hamiltonian and the angular momentum is common when it comes to solving spherical symmetric Hamiltonian. And standard textbooks like the ones written by Griffiths or Sakurai use this trick in the chapter of solving eigenfunctions of a hydrogen atom.

Comment: I think I found countrexample for your answer. Take a look at  updated **My attempt**. I found that there is inseparable function that satisfies that differential equation describing particle on spherical shell. I think this equation might be inconsistent with boundary conditions. $f(\theta,\phi)=f(\theta+2\pi n_1, \phi+2\pi n_2)$

Comment: Your attempt does not hold as a counterexample. If we say $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\theta+\phi$ is a solution, we need $\cot{\theta}+\epsilon\theta+\epsilon\phi=0$ for any $\theta$ and $\phi$ while having $\epsilon$ fixed to some constant. This is not the case, really.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to prove this although the proof is a two-step proof.

First, separation of variables in an *assumption* on the form of your solution.  In other words, assume the solution is separable and verify that a separable solution can be found.

It’s not the only way to deal with PDE (you could try the method of characteristics) but separation of variables has the advantage of transforming the PDE to ODEs, for which there are multiple techniques.

What is less trivial is to show that *all* solutions must be linear combinations of the separable ones.  This follows from [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).  In other words, even if you specialized your search to solutions of a specific (separable) form, you lost nothing because *all* solutions are superpositions of separable solutions.

Comment: This textbook I referred to was meant for chemists. There separability according to Autor is justified by inserting separated function in differential equation and seeing that obtained differential equation can be separated in two single-variable differential equations. I am guessing that according to Autor separability of wave-function should be "self-evident" to readers. I am guessing that answer should be simple. May be it has to do something with linear operator properties.

Comment: again: you *try* separability and *if* it works you continue with it.  Yes with a bit of experience it’s self-evident in the same way that the correct transformation needed to integrate a complicated function is “self-evident” with a bit of experience.  In other words: it is “trial-and-error” guided by experience but once you can separate all the Sturm-Liouville machinery helps you complete the “proof”.

Comment: Take a look at updated **My attempt**, there I showed that there is inseparable function that satisfies the differential equation describing particle on the spheric shell. Although this solution is inconsistent with boundary conditions which i didn't mentioned, function must be periodic for all variables with period $2\pi$. So if all solutions are separable it must have something to do with boundary conditions, not only the PDE.

Comment: so you found a particular form that does not solve your problem because the BC are wrong: I'm not sure what's gained there.  Moreover, the separation ansatz could be  product $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$, or $\Theta(\theta)+\Phi(\phi)$.  The product form the more common assumption, but  a sum functions is less frequent although it does occur in Hamilton-Jacobi theory.

Answer (score 1):

> where $\Lambda^2$ is the Legendrian and $\epsilon=\frac{2IE}{\hbar^2}$.

You did not provide an explicit equation for your Legendrian operator. But I assume you mean:
$$
\Lambda^2 = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$

> And I need to prove that $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$.

You already know that the solutions have the form of Spherical Harmonics. So, basically, it seems like you are trying to re-derive the form of the Spherical Harmonics.

What you do is just plug in the form
$$
\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)
$$
as an **ansatz** and show that it works.

You need to plug in a solution of this form and show that you can completely separate the variables. You will see that you end up with one term that only depends on $\theta$ and one that only depends on $\phi$.

You will introduce a "separation constant" called "$-m^2$" and you will see that:
$$
\frac{1}{\Phi}\frac{d^2\Phi}{d\phi^2} = -m^2\;,
$$
etc.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer reminds me several arguments from Atkins textbook of physical chemistry. I have read them. I should have emphasized more on that I am interested in validation of this method. I wrote this question because I was concerned why this justification of function separability works.

Comment: It's an ansatz. It works because it works. You don't need any further justification because you already seen that the guess has worked. The method *is* validated because we showed that the guess is right. If you are asking how to justify guessing, the only justification is well what else are you going to do? Just give up? No. You proceed by trying **something** because there is no other way.

Comment: You can buy a textbook on partial differential equations and study different kinds of guesses to try. But if you don't know the solution you have to try something, that is either going to be looking up the known solution or trying something else (a guess).

Comment: No. I am concerned about why obtained solution is general. So we found solution for wave-functions that splits in product. Why can we infer that there are no wave-functions that satisfy the PDE and are not separable.

Comment: You think this won't be explained in a PDE textbook?

Comment: I am chemist. I can't read math books like story books. Probably I need to invest a lot of time to find proper books and study them. It may take half a year. I am a bussy man.

Answer (score 1):

Like @hft said, the method of separation of variables uses an *ansatz*. An ansatz is an assumption of the form that your solution takes on.

In this case we simply *assume* that the wave function is a product of functions of each variable:

$$\psi(\theta,\phi) = \Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi). $$

It is not a fact. However, this assumption allows us to figure out genuine solutions of the 3D Schrödinger equation$^2$. That this method produces genuine solutions to the differential equations is enough to prove that the ansatz is valid.

Crucially, *the genuine solutions we obtain via separation of variables can form (via linear combination) any solution to the given Schrödinger equation.* In this case, we say that the solutions form a basis for the solution space. So via separation of variables, we have found a way to construct **all solutions** of the given differential equation. The fact that the solutions we found form a basis for the solution space is a *very special* property of the given differential equation$^1$.

Note: the equation you call "the wave-function" is actually the 3D Schrödinger equation. Wave functions are normalizable solutions to the Schrödinger equation (i.e. wave functions are the $\psi$s).

In general, it seems like differential equations are called "equations" (e.g. the Legendre equation) and their solutions are called "functions".

[1] Under "Applicability", there is an outline of an argument as to why separation of variables works to find a basis for the solution space in cases like the one you're interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables.

[2] Via separation of variables, you split the original Schrödinger equation (a partial differential equation because it depends on more than one variable) into two second order ordinary differential equations (order meaning the highest derivative present, which is the second derivative in this case). There is a theorem somewhere that says an N-order differential equation has N linearly independent solutions. Thus, we should expect two linearly independent solutions from $\Theta(\theta)$ and $\Phi(\phi)$. There ends up being only one from $\Theta$ because the other linearly independent solution is physically unacceptable. And, we get two for $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you. My question was about why it is valid to assume that wave-function is separable.

Comment: It is valid to assume that the wave function is separable because it produces a genuine solution to the differential equation. The author knew this when writing their textbook, but there is no obvious way to see this being true without trying it oneself. 

Some differential equations cannot even be solved analytically and must be solved numerically (i.e. literally putting numbers in to see if the equations work).

Comment: I couldn't understand it yet. They seem to hard. I know calculus I and II and partially calculus III, also analytical geometry I. I also can solve some single-variable differential equations. I am Msc of Chemistry.

Comment: If you're ever interested in learning a math subject important for quantum mechanics (and quantum chemistry, then), you should look into Linear Algebra :). @AlexAlex

Comment: I had cource liaear algebra and analytical geometry I. Thank you. I will invest my time in that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a proof (with all mathematical rigour), but if you see that the Hamiltonian is a sum of terms that only contains one of the variables, you can solve the differential equation by separating variables.

In your case, the differential equation is
$$ \left[\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}} + \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)\right]\psi(\theta,\phi) = E\psi(\theta,\phi) $$
By inspection, you see that there are a $\theta$ term together with a partial derivative with respect to $\phi$. However, you can also verify that using a wavefunction as $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$ your problem becomes
$$ \frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)}\frac{d^{2}\Phi(\phi)}{d\phi^{2}} + \frac{\sin\theta}{\Theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{d\Theta}{d\theta}\right) - E\sin^{2}\theta = 0 $$
You see, the first term now is only depending on $\phi$ and the second and third terms only contains the $\theta$ variable. From this, you can solve two simpler differential equations for each variable.

It might not be really clear why you have to try a product wavefunction here, but it is usually the case when you have $N$-dimensional problems with $N>1$. In other words, you think of each dimension of space as independent of the other, and the problem will tell you if that assumption will give you the correct result.

Comment: Your argument reminds that are presented in Atkins textbook. I am interested primarily why this method of proving separability works. I want a proof of this method validity preferably written in predicate logic and in Fitch's notation.